# Symbol _TCP_ENDPOINT not found

Tags: windows, memory, windbg, crash-dumps, volatility

I've been reading "The art of memory forensics", on chapter 11 page 327 they added the output of Windbg `dt(_TCP_ENDPOINT)` [The Art Of Memory Forensics - _TCP_ENDPOINT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7x7k7.png)

I have been trying to get the same result with Windbg but I keep getting the same error:

```
dt(_TCP_ENDPOINT)
Symbol _TCP_ENDPOINT not found.
```

even though I loaded the tcpip.sys symbols file

```
1: kd> lml
start             end                 module name
....... 
fffff805`3bfc0000 fffff805`3c2a9000   tcpip      (pdb symbols)          C:\ProgramData\Dbg\sym\tcpip.pdb\4EF7BCB071F28E1DAAAA937D59B39D121\tcpip.pdb
```

I dont get this kind of error when looking other Kernel structures,

```
1: kd>  dt(_EPROCESS)
ntdll!_EPROCESS
   +0x000 Pcb              : _KPROCESS
   +0x2e0 ProcessLock      : _EX_PUSH_LOCK
   ......
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `_TCP_ENDPOINT` appears to be an overlay defined in volatility's netscan plugin. You won't find it in `tcpip.sys` because it never was there to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output in the book was from the dt() command from the [volshell](http://axlotldunktank.blogspot.com/p/volshell.html) plugin in volatility 2.7, not Windbg.

And like [@dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv) said, `_TCP_ENDPOINT` is an overlay used by Volatility.